# Detecting javascript crashes client-side

Tags: javascript, error-handling, runtime-error

I wrote a rather large single page application, and I am about to deploy it to a restricted audience.
I would like to be able to:

- Detect NASTY Javascript errors (e.g. accessing an object that doesn't exist, call functions that do not exist, etc.)
- When one happens, get as much info as possible( stacktrace, variable values, anything I can)
- Make a POST to the server, telling admins about the problem that just happened

Has this been done before?
How does this work/fight/doesn't work against code minification/obfuscation etc.?

Before I reinvent yet another wheel, is there a full library that does all this already?

Comment: Why not just debug the code and make sure it all works?

Comment: yeah, it's called jshint

Comment: Read [Capture and report JavaScript errors with window.onerror](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/01/04/client-javascript-reporting-window-onerror.html) (or other similar articles).

Comment: @Pointy Because some of the errors might come from errors from the server. For example children data not loaded properly and missing the `_children` property and the program expecting `_children.gigId.chatName`. While YES checking each object before using it is what we try and do, sometimes things are missed (also because this is just ONE example). When you develop things that are much bigger than tiny applications, you cannot expect the code to be 100% perfect.

Comment: @SergioAlen Try and preempt errors like the one I described above with JSHint

Comment: well from the server it's another story, maybe this ? https://sentry.io/welcome/

Comment: @SergioAlen Most unpredictable errors will come from external sources (database, or user input). That's when things are tricky.

Comment: @nnnnnn Would you please add that as an answer? I will accept it right away. That's exactly what I needed

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to write a detailed answer, and link-only answers are frowned upon. You can always add an answer yourself with details of what you end up implementing.

Answer (score 0):

https://sentry.io/welcome/

Looks pretty complete for-front end and back-end bug reporting.

Good luck!